# Update Ciphers in GKE

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, gke-networking

We have a microservice based application deployed on GKE. The outbound request from this GKE is routed through a NAT gateway the

One of our Integration partner has deprecated a cipher. Now we need to update the cipher for a specific workload. looking for a suggestion how it can be made.

Comment: "We have a microservice based application deployed on GKE. The outbound request from this GKE is routed through a NAT gateway the"

- Can you complete this statement and provide further details regarding your end goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue from the application code and is corrected from code by adding the necessary Ciphers.